# Confidence interval for categorical data

Tags: r, confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution

I have the following data about companies who respond timely or untimely and another category of the answer:

```
           ND  NI  SC  PI  PA
Timely     27   3   9   4   7
Untimely   24  14  14   6   8
```

I want to do the following:

1. Write the multinomial model for the data and the hypothesis for the two possible categorizations.
2. Do an appropriate test for independence between the two possible categorizations?
3. Make a 95% independence interval for the ratio of companies in the PA-category.

**My approach**:

**1.**

I create the following models:

$$
M_0:\quad \{X_{ij}\} \sim \mathrm{Multinom}(116,\{\pi_{ij}\}) \\
\pi_{ij} \ge 0, \sum_{ij}\pi_{ij}=1
$$

$$
M_1:\quad \{X_{ij}\} \sim \mathrm{Multinom}(116,\{\pi_{ij}\}) \\
\pi_{ij}=\alpha_i\beta_j \\
\alpha_i \ge 0, \sum_{i}\alpha_i=1, \quad \beta_j \ge 0, \sum_j \beta_j=1 \\
$$

I formulate the hypothesis as the following:

$$
H_0: \quad \pi_{ij}=\alpha_i \text{ for alle } i=1,2 \text{ and } j=1,2,\dots ,5
$$

**2.**

I do this test in R. Since I get an expected value below 5, I use Fisher's test instead of the G test:

```
mat=rbind(c(27,3,9,4,7),c(24,14,14,6,8))
fisher.test(mat)

Output:
p-value = 0.1377
```

So I cannot reject the hypothesis that the two categories are independent.

**3.**

Here I have a hunch that I should find the confidence interval for a binomial distribution, but I'm stuck. I would like to calculate this in R too.

**EDIT: updated question**

Comment: It may make sense to use a binomial confidence interval.  But I think you have to specify how you are thinking about the data.  For example, if ND, NI, SC, PI, PA are groups and Timely/Untimely are the observed results, you would want a confidence interval for each group, e.g. *binom.test(27, (27+24))*.  Note that this is looking at the data in a different way than the answer by @lewiso1 .

Comment: The discussion here may be helpful: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Post-hoc_for_Contingency_table_4x2_chi-square_test

Answer (score 0):

For point 3, the 'naive' approach might be to calculate individual confidence intervals for each category within each colour. 
For example:

```
green <- c(27,3,9,4,7)
binom.test(green[1], sum(green), alternative="two.sided", conf.level=0.95)
```

But the categories aren't independent, so if you had a 95% chance of getting any given proportion correct, you've got a less than 95% chance of getting ALL proportions correct (0.95^(number of categories) ~ 0.77). This is nicely described here: https://brownmath.com/stat/gof_ci.htm

There are several more sophisticated ways to go about it.  I'm not an R user so can't go in-depth, but I found a great package that calculates multiple different approaches to confidence intervals of categorical data, see: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/scimple

The example usage is self explanatory but might go something like this:

```
library(scimple)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(tidyverse)

green <- c(27,3,9,4,7)
z <- 0.05

scimple_ci(green, z) %>% 
  mutate(method=scimple_short_to_long[method]) -> cis
```

As for plotting and processing of the output, I'm afraid I can't help because of my unfamiliarity with R.

However `statsmodels` in python has two implementations (Goodman or Sison-Glaz), and here's enough to calculate CIs using Sison-Glaz method and plot to compare:

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import multinomial_proportions_confint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

green = np.array([27,3,9,4,7])
blue = np.array([24,14,14,6,8])
ci_green = multinomial_proportions_confint(green, alpha=0.05, method='sison-glaz')
ci_blue = multinomial_proportions_confint(blue, alpha=0.05, method='sison-glaz')

_=plt.fill_between(np.arange(5), ci_green[:,0], ci_green[:,1], alpha=0.5, label='Green sample', color='green')
_=plt.fill_between(np.arange(5), ci_blue[:,0], ci_blue[:,1], alpha=0.5, label='Blue sample', color='blue')
plt.ylabel('Proportion')
plt.xlabel('Category')
_=plt.xticks(np.arange(5),['ND', 'NI', 'SC',  'PI',  'PA'])
_=plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

I think that supports the output from your Fisher comparison.

Comment: What do you mean by "the categories are not independent"? Didn't I show that the two possible categorization systems are independent with Fisher's test?

Comment: I have edited the question, since I think I may have mistranslated the last question.

Comment: The two classes 'Timely' and 'Untimely' (which used to be 'Green' and 'Blue' in the original question) could be considered two samples. Within each sample you have a discrete categorical distribution, consisting of categories: `ND, NI, SC, PI, PA`. It is these categories that I refer to as not being independent - that's because when the proportion of one increases, it necessarily means the proportion of all the others decrease, thus the categories within a sample are dependent on each other.

Comment: Did you have any success with the scimple library?

Comment: This is a good approach, only if you're interested in confidence intervals for all categories simultaneously.  The binomial confidence interval retains its coverage properties when you want a CI for a single group (which is what I think OP is looking for).

Comment: In R, the *MultinomCI* function in the *DescTools* package has options for multinomial CI's, including Sison-Glaz and Goodman.